# Defining generic concat function

Tags: swift, generics, functional-programming

My definition is:

```swift
func concat<A>(_ xs: [A]) -> A {
    return xs.flatMap( {x in x} )
}
```

The compiler gives this warning:

> Cannot convert return expression of type `'[A]'` to return type `'A'`.

Could someone point out what's wrong with my type signature ? How can I solve it ?

Comment: I think error could not be more clear, your function `concat<A>` specifies that it takes an array of generic element `A` and returns a single element of type `A` and it has only one statement in it which simply flat maps the array, output of flat map of collection is not a single element its a array (of non nil elements from collection you called flat map on) clearly your return statement and return type declaration are not in sync and compiler is exactly complaining the same. It says youre returning an [A] where as you were supposed to return A

Comment: If you are writing a Generic concat, flatmap is definitely not the write operator, also if I pass array of strings "A","B","C" output might be ABC, what if I pass 1,2,3 will it be 123 or 6(1+2+3) Generic concat operator might not make sense and you might need to handle proper operation based on type, what are u trying to achieve here?

Comment: Thanks for your input, @SandeepBhandari. In this specific case, isn't `A` of type `[Int]` ? Then, it follows that `[A]` would be `[[Int]]`. Does that make sense ? If I understand correctly, generic `A` could be itself an array. However, I could be wrong.

Comment: @F.Zer Your reasoning correct, except this: "If I understand correctly, generic A could be itself an array." It *can* be, but with the types you wrote, it doesn't need to be. If there's any case in which you have `A` being a non-sequence, then you can't rely on `A` being a sequence. This is why you need `A` to be constrained, as I explain in my new Answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would like to make a generic concatenate method that would work with any type of collection (including Strings) you need to constraint your generic type to `RangeReplaceableCollection` protocol which requires that all types that conform to it to implement a [generic initializer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/rangereplaceablecollection/3018257-init). You can use that initializer to initialize a new collection with the result of your flatMap method:

```
func concat<A: RangeReplaceableCollection>(_ xs: [A]) -> A {
    .init(xs.flatMap { $0 })
}
```

---

Or extending Sequence protocol and constraining its Element to RangeReplaceableCollection:

```
extension Sequence where Element: RangeReplaceableCollection {
    var concatenated: Element { .init(flatMap { $0 } ) }
}
```

---

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6]].concatenated    // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
["ab", "cde"].concatenated               // "abcde"
```

Comment: This is spectacular. Thank you so much, @Leo Dabus ! Exactly what I needed.

Comment: Could you explain how you are using a bare `.init` in the first concat ? On which object is it operating ?

Comment: @F.Zer Swift is a type inferred language. It is the same as `A(xs.flatMap{$0})` or `Element(flatMap{$0})`. `RangeReplaceableCollection` protocol requires that all types that conform to it to implement a generic initializer. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/rangereplaceablecollection/3018257-init

Answer (score 1):

There's two issues here.

`[A]` is just a shorthand for `Array<A>`. The implementation of [`flatMap` for `Array<Element>`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/3126947-flatmap) has this declaration:

```
func flatMap<SegmentOfResult>(
    _ transform: (Element) throws -> SegmentOfResult
) rethrows -> [SegmentOfResult.Element]
where SegmentOfResult : Sequence
```

First notice that the result of `flatMap` is an Array. This is the first issue, your function should declare a return type of `[A]`, not `A`.

Once you make that change, you'll notice this warning:

> `flatMap` is deprecated: Please use `compactMap(_:)` for the case where closure returns an optional value

Notice that the closure is expected to have type `(Element) -> SegmentOfResult`, where `SegmentOfResult` is some sequence. In your case, your closure, `{ x in x }` just has a type of `A -> A`. Because `A` is just a free generic type (and not required to be a `Sequence`), it's not a sequence, so this closure is not the correct type for this version of `flatMap`.

The type checker then tries an alternate route. It sees another overload of [`flatMap` available](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/3126949-flatmap):

```
func flatMap<ElementOfResult>(
    _ transform: (Element) throws -> ElementOfResult?
) rethrows -> [ElementOfResult]
```

Its closure expects to have type `(Element) -> ElementOfResult?`. The type checker is actually able to achieve this, by applying automatic optional promotion to your closure, as if you had written `{ x in Optional(x) }`. This has a type of `(A) -> A`, and matches the type required for this overload. It works, except it's not what you meant.

This overload has been renamed to `compactMap`, and has been deprecated. This is probably why :P

So to solve the second problem, you would need to constrain to be a `Sequence`, and return the `Element` of `A`, not `A` itself:

```
func concat<A: Sequence>(_ xs: [A]) -> [A.Element] {
    return xs.flatMap { (x: A) -> A in x }
}


print(concat([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6]])) // => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: This wouldn't work for an array of strings. It would return an array of characters instead of a string

Comment: @LeoDabus That "works", it's just a matter of problem specification. OP didn't say anything about wanting the result to be of any particular type

Comment: To make it really generic what OP needs is `func concat<A: RangeReplaceableCollection>(_ xs: [A]) -> A {` `.init(xs.flatMap { $0 } )` `}`

Comment: `concat<A>(_ xs: [A]) -> A` seems pretty self explanatory anyway it is just my opinion

Comment: Ohh that's really nice. You should put that in an answer!

Comment: This is an excellent explanation. Upvoted. Thank you so much, @Alexander !